# Error with custom listview with Customarrayadapter

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

I am following a custom listview tutorial [here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/) that I'm not sure what is causing. The logcat is:

```
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969): Process: com.skateconnect, PID: 26969
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at com.skateconnect.android.adapters.CustomBaseAdapter.getView(CustomBaseAdapter.java:57)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16573)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5147)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16573)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5147)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16573)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5147)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at  com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16573)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5147)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16573)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2064)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1078)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5861)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-13 14:00:51.346: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where custombaseadapter.java looks like:

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = items;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
 TextView pid;
 ImageView image;
 TextView name;
 TextView distance;
 TextView date;
 TextView time;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
        context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.pid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pid);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);

    holder.pid.setText(rowItem.getpid());
    holder.image.setImageResource(rowItem.getimage());
    holder.name.setText(rowItem.getname());
    holder.distance.setText(rowItem.getdisp_dist());
    holder.date.setText(rowItem.getdate());
    holder.time.setText(rowItem.gettime());
    /*

     */
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
}
```

and line 57 is

```
holder.pid.setText(rowItem.getpid());
```

I'm still getting used to custom adapters so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Tyler

EDIT: rowItem is NULL
EDIT2: How it is populated:

```
                for (int i = 0; i < spots.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = spots.getJSONObject(i);
                    search_trig=0;

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String strlong = c.getString(TAG_LONG);
                    double elong = Double.parseDouble(strlong);
                    String strlat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                    double elat = Double.parseDouble(strlat);
                    double dist = getDistance(slat, slong, elat, elong);
                    String distance = String.format("%.1f", dist);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String pave = c.getString(TAG_PAVEMENT);
                    String traffic = c.getString(TAG_TRAFFIC);
                    String enviro = c.getString(TAG_ENVIRONMENT);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String image_B64 = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_B64);
                    String dist_display = distance+ " Mi";
                    String timeAway=".";
                    type=".";
                    date=".";
                    time=".";
                    //EVENT STUFF
                    if(add.equals("Event")){
                        //need to add other stuff too
                        type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                        date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                        time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                        timeAway = String.valueOf(getTimeAWAY(date));
                    }
                    image = getDispImage(type,enviro);
                    if(search_bp==1){
                        //checks distance
                        if(str_dist.equals("Any")==false){
                        if((dist>Double.parseDouble(str_dist))){
                            search_trig=1;
                        }
                        }

                        if(str_pavement.equals("Any")==false){
                        if((str_pavement.equals(pave)==false)){
                            search_trig=1;
                        }
                        }

                        if(str_traffic.equals("Any")==false){
                        if((str_traffic.equals(traffic)==false)){
                            search_trig=1;
                        }
                        }

                        if(str_enviro.equals("Any")==false){
                        if((str_enviro.equals(enviro)==false)){
                            search_trig=1;
                        }
                        }

                        //EVENT STUFF
                        if(add.equals("Event")){

                            if(str_type.equals("Any")==false){
                                if((str_type.equals(type)==false)){
                                    search_trig=1;
                                }
                                }

                        }
                        item = new RowItem(id,image,name,distance,date,time,dist_display,timeAway);
                        shr_spots.put(id, new SHARE(id, name,strlong,strlat,pave,traffic,enviro,image_B64,date,time,type)); 


                        if(search_trig == 0){
                            //spotsList.add(map); 
                            rowItems.add(item);
                            n=1;
                        }
                    }else{
                        //spotsList.add(map);
                         rowItems.add(item);

                        n=1;
                    }
                }
```

initialized as

```
rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
```

EDIT3:

```
CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(AllSpotsActivity.this, rowItems);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Have you made sure this line: `(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pid);` is returning a non-null object?

Comment: Same goes for this one: `RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);` One of those are returning null and that assignation is setting some value on a `null` object.

Comment: Use debugger to see what has null value. Make sure your xml layout for row is correct. It is really simple to debug.

Comment: rowItem is null so getItem(position) is returning null

Comment: @TylerM `getItem` performs the operation on the internal "copy of your data", i.e., the third of the parameters you set when calling the constructor. Maybe you've made some additional operation (deleting mostly) and didn't update that data structure?

Comment: So if there are extra items in public class RowItem() then that could be causing the problem?

Comment: Could you provide the snippet where you initialize your Custom `ArrayAdapter` and how you populate it?

Comment: Okay I think I added what you asked?

Comment: Nope... I can't see any `CustomArrayAdapter` initialization in what you've added.

Comment: Sorry wrong initialization, it should be the right one now

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);
```

maybe getItem(position) returned null. Then afterwards you try to call getpid() on it => NPE

Put a breakpoint at this line and check the values in the debugger or alternatively output the values to the logcat to confirm that. Then adjust your code to check for null values before calling methods on it.

**Update:** After digging through the for-loop that populates your list I have seen the following part at the end:

```
                }else{
                    //spotsList.add(map);
                     rowItems.add(item);

                    n=1;
                }
```

so you add "item" to your list, but you never set it for the else-case in your if statement.

You do set item only for the case if(search_bp==1) but not for the case it is not.

So in the end you end up adding the item values from before entering the for-loop to your list.

Try assigning proper item values for this case, maybe like this:

```
                  }else{
                     //spotsList.add(map);
                     item = new RowItem(id,image, //etc.
                     rowItems.add(item);
                  }
```

Well alternatively, just don't add the item at all to your list in this case. Depends on what you want ;-)

I hope my guess was right and helped solving your problem.

Comment: rowItem is returning null. What could be causing that?

Comment: then `getItem(position);` might return null for that position. Review how you set the items in your code. Anyhow check `if(rowItem != null) {...}` before calling .getpid() on it

Comment: okay, with the check everything works fine, as in it doesn't put anything up but it does not crash. Could it be that I have more items in public class RowItem {} that i have for named with holder.?

Comment: check the constructor of CustomBaseAdapter. it has a List<RowItem> items parameter. Check the values in the list that you use for constructing it.

Comment: do you mean this: CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(AllSpotsActivity.this, rowItems);?

Comment: yes, check the values in the rowItems list (in debugger or output to logcat)

Comment: Could it be that for rowItem there is pid, image, name, distance, date, time, time_away, disp_dist. While the custom adapter only handles all but the last 2?

Answer (score 0):

Your populating functions (though a little bit caotical) seems ok, your constructor seems ok, so since your stacktrace references to measuring errors, it can just be a layout issue.

When inflating, you're calling:

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
```

Try replacing this line by:

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

Comment: Could it be that for rowItem there is pid, image, name, distance, date, time, time_away, disp_dist. While the custom adapter only handles all but the last 2?

Comment: If you're just starting with `Adapter`s, I'd recommend extending `ArrayAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter`. In the latter you have to be aware on overriding some things I don't know you are. Try by extending `ArrayAdapter` and once you've understood it, try with `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: Is there anything I would need to change/get rid of if I try it with arrayAdapter?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend this reference as it goes step by step: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

change your return statement.

change 
return convertView;

with 
return view;

here view will be your inflated view.